# Check if camera is busy with another apps

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I'm tracking that if any app is using camera or not with code below

```
public boolean isCameraBusy() {
Camera camera = null;
try {
    camera = Camera.open();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    return true;
} finally {
    if (camera != null) camera.release();
}
 return false;
}
```

I need to use this inside onResume method .. My app is using camera so everytime it will be busy when I resume ..
Is there a way to bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

your code gets a camera instance and then release it 
you should release it when u finish to use it and not after getting a reference to the instance..

u should use the release method on your onPause() method

**Edit:**

then u should do that like this on the onResume():

```
    if (camera != null) camera.release();
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by using method `Camera.open(cameraId)`

If the camera will opened by other applications than it will throw the Exception.

Example:

```
public boolean isCameraUsebyAnotherApp() {
    Camera camerastatus = null;
    try {
        camerastatus = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (camerastatus != null) camerastatus.release();
    }
    return false;
}
```

May this helps you.